# Java GridBagLayout with components inside

Tags: java, swing, grid, jcomponent, gridbaglayout

I am trying to get GridBagLayout with two panels to be 40% and 60% of the frame while being able to have components inside of them and it is being troublesome.

When I do not place the button inside the panel, it works just like I want it to.

Not quite sure what I am doing wrong and I have tried moving the creation of the button to where the panel on the GridBagLayout is created, but it still didn't work.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Test{

public void display(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(900,650);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    JPanel test = new JPanel();
    test.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c= new GridBagConstraints();

    JPanel left= new JPanel();
    JPanel right= new JPanel();

    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL - GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.weightx = 0.4;
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.weighty = 1;
    test.add(left,c);
    c.weightx = .6;
    c.gridx = 2;
    test.add(right,c);

    JButton button= new JButton("A button");
    left.add(button,c);//If I do not add this, then it shows how I want it to be

    frame.add(test);
   }
}
```

Comment: What is `createVector` ?

Comment: Sorry, renamed it to button, was from something else.

Comment: It looks like two panels with a 40/60% split when I run it, with or without the button. What is it exactly that is the problem?

Comment: Also, instead of `GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL - GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL`, are you sure you don't just want `GridBagConstraints.BOTH`?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html about 2/3rds down the page should help you out. Also, as the article states you could always use NetBeans if you're stuggling to do it by hand then just view the source.

Comment: Greenday - That was the link that I was using and it got me as far as what I have shown. Ash - It still isn't showing for me the correct split, so now I am not sure what is up.

Comment: @Ash Nevermind, I changed it to both and adjusted it to 70 and 30 % and it is moving properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing with the weights is that they describe what to do with the extra space. The components have their preferred, min and max dimensions which the layout manager uses when it calculates the layout. The GridBagLayout then splits the extra space using these weights. In your case, i think the space that is split equals 900-button.getPreferredSize().width. You are splitting maybe 800 pixels into 320 and 480.

Answer (score 0):

here is an example of a panel created with GridBagLayout: (don't bother about swing factory, just create a component instead)

```
private void buildSourcePanel() {

  JPanel pnlSource = new JPanel();

  GridBagLayout gbl_pnlSource = new GridBagLayout();
  gbl_pnlSource.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
  gbl_pnlSource.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0, 100, 100, 25};
  pnlSource.setLayout(gbl_pnlSource);

  final JLabel lblFolderMask = swingFactory.createLabel(" SOURCE DIRECTORY ", null, null, SwingConstants.LEFT, SwingConstants.CENTER, true);
  pnlSource.add(lblFolderMask, new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0, 10, 1, new Insets(5, 5, 5, 0), 0, 0));

  txtSource = swingFactory.createTextField(null, "txtSource", null, SystemColor.textHighlight, SwingConstants.LEFT, false, true, "Source Directory");
  pnlSource.add(txtSource, new GridBagConstraints(1, 0, 1, 1, 1.0, 0.0, 10, 1, new Insets(5, 0, 5, 5), 0, 0));

  final JButton btnBrowse = new JButton("Browse...");
  btnBrowse.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 0, false), new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5)));
  btnBrowse.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 14));
  pnlSource.add(btnBrowse, new GridBagConstraints(2, 0, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0, 10, 1, new Insets(5, 0, 5, 5), 0, 0));

  final JButton btnClear = new JButton("Clear...");
  btnClear.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 0, false), new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5)));
  btnClear.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 14));
  pnlSource.add(btnClear, new GridBagConstraints(3, 0, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0, 10, 1, new Insets(5, 0, 5, 5), 0, 0));

  lblStatus = swingFactory.createLabel(null, null, null, SwingConstants.CENTER, SwingConstants.CENTER, false);
  pnlSource.add(lblStatus, new GridBagConstraints(4, 0, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0, 10, 1, new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5), 0, 0));
}
```